# Clustering data with same column and merging its parameters adn remove other entries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, procedure

I have a database with following column and simple snippet of data :

```
p-id    Name      Size
20036   Prod_123   L
20043   Prod_123   M
20094   Prod_123   XL
20249   Prod_123   S
35188   Prod_826   L
45325   Prod_826   M
39407   Prod_826   XL
20691   Prod_826   XXL
```

I would like to cluster all the data with same product name  and also would like to merge its column called size so that I will get all the values.
So I want my output to look like

```
p-id    Name      Size
20036   Prod_123   L,M,XL,S
35118   Prod_826   L,M,XL,XXL
```

I want to do this with Procedure or if possible then with by query also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(size) FROM <<table>> GROUP BY name;
```

or

```
SELECT min(p_id),name, GROUP_CONCAT(size) FROM <<table>> GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: i want to to update database it self and would like to have only 2rows for all the given records.